# factorygirl order of parameters break create() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Why does:

fi = FactoryGirl.create(:finder_item, store_id: s.id, :category_foo, :random_question)

throw an error `finder_item_spec.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)`

but simply re-ordering so the the traits are before the assignment works fine:

fi = FactoryGirl.create(:finder_item, :category_foo, :random_question, store_id: s.id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your arguments is not just symbol type - it's `:key => value`, and for a FG order of arguments with different types is something that matters.

Comment: I wonder if that is documented anywhere... if not, should be.

Comment: There's example in FG documentation which shows right order when traits used. Can you accept answer?

Comment: It's standard Ruby practice to put the hash at the end of your parameter list - this is because otherwise they must have explicit braces. This is why you're getting a Ruby parsing error - it's not even getting to FactoryGirl.

Comment: Thanks, tho I tried with braces and it still didn't work. But hey, it is what it is!

Comment: What I was saying was that APIs in Ruby normally expect the hash as the last parameter, and you can expect that is the most common case. One common exception is when there are several hashes. If you added the explicit braces you wouldn't get the Ruby parsing error, but you still wouldn't be using FactoryGirl as it expected.